# What’s the best way to use a Canon 60D as a webcam on MacOS?

Tags: canon, mac, usb

I want to use my Canon 60D as a webcam. I have tried using [CameraLive2](https://github.com/v002/v002-Camera-Live) and [CamTwist](http://camtwiststudio.com/) as outlined here:

https://swizec.com/blog/connected-canon-dslr-webcam/swizec/7477

It seems to disconnect after a few seconds.

I’ve seen other methods that basically screen capture the output of the EOS Utility app, but this wastes a lot of screenspace and is quite hacky. Is there a better way just using software? I’d rather not buy an HDMI blackmagic adapter box if I don’t have to.

Can the [magic lantern](https://magiclantern.fm/) firmware help with this? I’ve updated to the latest Canon firmware on the 60D but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have found, using Canon 60D on Mac has the following challenges:

- There's currently no listed EOS Webcam Utility for Canon 60D on Mac. There do seem to be some people succeeding with workarounds by installing drivers for similar Canon models (e.g. 77D) - but I was not successful.
  --EDIT: As of 2020-11-11 there are now [drivers available](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/cameras/eos-dslr-and-mirrorless-cameras/dslr/eos-60d/eos-60d?tab=drivers_downloads) for 60D on Mac.
- Using micro-hdmi and a USB capture card, after flashing my 60D with the latest Magic Lantern firmware I was able to get 'clean hdmi' output, but was only able to get 480p output (instead of the almost-1080p output that should be possible).

You could perhaps have more luck with https://github.com/v002/v002-Camera-Live or waiting until updated Webcam utility drivers are released that support the 60D.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another software called [Cascable](https://cascable.se/pro-webcam/). It is by far the best solution for connecting unsupported cameras to macOS. No additional video capture hardware needed. Purely software and the software even provides some control over the camera like focus, light settings etc. It actually depends on the camera connected and which mode it is in. They even support the recent sandboxing changes in macOS if you are also into that kind of technical stuff.

At the time of this writing, I'm having [a minor issue](https://twitter.com/cansurmeli/status/1621807673313316864) with them where my video is captured but not distributed to the video conferencing apps but hopefully they will get back to me or release an update.